# Making a pop-up fully responsive using Flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, media-queries

I created a modal/pop-up containing a picture and text like this https://www.labtag.ca/. It's should be fully responsive across all the devices(vertical layout for mobiles and Ipads). It's good for large devices and when emulated all the standard device sizes in chrome but when resizing the browser and checking it looks out of order while doing it from large to small at certain widths and also in a real-time in mobiles, there is an unnecessary height that is being added upon the scroll. I used flex-direction: row for large devices and for small devices, I used flex-direction: column.I used a lot of media queries(not a good idea) to make sure that the padding(all directions) is good. Any insights on how to fix these problems and do this with fewer media queries. Here is my HTML:-

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">


  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="content-img-wrapper">
      <div class="img"><img src="https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server3300/p3n7fuwd/product_images/uploaded_images/computer.png" alt="ga-popup-img" /></div>
     <div class="content">
       <p>You're missing out <span id= "ga-icons">&#9632; &#9632; &#9632;</span></p>
       <ul>
         <li><i class="arrow right"></i>Access the latest products</li>
         <li><i class="arrow right"></i>Get discounts</li>
         <li><i class="arrow right"></i>Checkout in $CAD</li>
         <li><i class="arrow right"></i>Live Chat</li>
       </ul>
       <a href="https://www.labtag.com/" class="btn-ga">
        Take me to the new website  <i class="arrow-button"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is my css:-

```
/*start of ga popup*/
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
 position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 2; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: hidden; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */

}
i.right{ /*Style for the arrows*/
      border: solid #fc7a22;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
    transform: translate(0%,-40%) rotate(-45deg);
        margin-right: 10px;



    }
i.arrow-button{ /*Style for the arrows*/
      border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
    transform:  rotate(-45deg);
        margin-right: 10px;



    }
/*Making the image responsive*/
.content-img-wrapper .img img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

/*button inside the modal */
a.btn-ga {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #fc7a22;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    transition: all .4s ease;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 14.7rem;
    /* height: 4.8rem; */
    border-radius: .5rem;
    font-family: Amsi Pro Cond Bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
    /*letter-spacing: .07rem;*/
    line-height: 2rem;
    text-decoration:none;
    transform: translate(0%,140%);
    /* padding-top: 1.3rem; */
    /* border: 0; */
}

/*styling the content */
.content-img-wrapper{
   display: flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
}
.content-img-wrapper .content p {
    /* justify-content: space-around; */
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family:'Atlas Grotesk Bold';
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #351f65;
    /*transform: translateY(-120%);*/

}
.content-img-wrapper .content ul {
  list-style-type: none;
    border: unset;

}
.content-img-wrapper .content ul li {
    /* justify-content: space-around; */
    font-size: 33.5px;
    color: #351f65;
    font-family:'Atlas Grotesk Regular';
    /*transform: translate(-10%,-80%);*/
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: unset;
}
.content-img-wrapper .content ul li:before {
   /* content: "• ";
    color: #53c5e9; */

}
/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width:  70%;
  height: 70%;

 transform: translate(0%, 8%);
}


.content-img-wrapper{


    /*padding-top: 80px;*/


}


.content-img-wrapper .img {
    width: unset;
    height: unset;
    padding: 20px
}
.content-img-wrapper.content{
  padding: 20px

}
a.btn-ga:hover{
    color:#fff !important;
    }
/* The Close Button */
.close {
  /*color: #aaaaaa;*/
  color:#c2c2c2;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
        transform: translate(-40%,40%);
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*unicode icons*/
#ga-icons{
  font-size:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
/*For phones till ipad pro*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width:  100%;
  height: 80%;


}
.content-img-wrapper .img img{
    /*width:90%;*/
        margin-left: 8px;
    }
}
/* For just phones*/
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.content-img-wrapper{
 flex-direction: column;
}
  .content-img-wrapper .content p {
    /* justify-content: space-around; */
    font-size: 25px;
    transform:unset;

}
.content-img-wrapper .content ul li {
   font-size: 15px;

    transform: translate(-10%,100%);
}
.content {
    transform: translate(15%);
}
.modal-content {
    width:90%;
    min-height: 90%;

transform:unset;
}
i.right{
transform: scale(0.7)translate(0%,-20%) rotate(-45deg);
}

}
@media screen and  (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 360px) {
    .modal{
        padding-top:unset;
        }
.modal-content {

    height: 82%;
}
.content-img-wrapper .content p {

    font-size: 22px;
}

}
@media  screen 
    and (device-width : 375px) 
    and (device-height : 812px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) { 
.modal-content {
    width: 90%;
    height: 64%;

}

}
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 411px) 
  and (device-height: 823px) 

   {
.modal-content {
    width: 90%;
    height: 66%;

}

}

@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 568px) 

   {
.content {
    transform: translate(11%);
}

}
/*Ipad and Ipad pro specific styles*/
@media  screen 
  and (min-width: 768px) 
  and (max-width: 1279px) 
  {
    .content {

    transform: translate(30%);
    }
    .content-img-wrapper .content ul li {

    transform: translate(-2%,132%);
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.content-img-wrapper {
    padding-top: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap:unset;
}
.content-img-wrapper .img img {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
      margin-left: 60px;
}

a.btn-ga {
        transform: translate(0%,80%);
    font-size: 2rem;
        line-height: 3rem;
        width: 29rem;
    height: 3rem;
    }
i.arrow-button {

    transform: scale(1.5)translateY(-25%) rotate(-45deg);
    margin-right: 10px;
}

}
/*For laptops and bigger*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .content-img-wrapper{

    justify-content: space-around;
    transform: translateY(30%);

}
.content-img-wrapper .content {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.modal-content {

  width: 1250px; 

}
.content-img-wrapper .content ul li{

        transform: translate(-4%,200%);
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
a.btn-ga{
    transform: translate(0%,200%);
    width:483px;
    font-size: 2rem;
        line-height: 4rem;
    height:58px;
    }
i.arrow-button {
    border: solid #fff;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-33%) rotate(-45deg);
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#ga-icons {
    font-size: 20px;

}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 800px){
.content-img-wrapper {
    transform: translateY(20%);
}


}

/*end of ga popup*/
```

Here is my js:-

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');



// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    if(window.location.href !='https://www.labtag.ca/'){
        return;
        }
  modal.style.display = "block";
  $('#Header,#TopMenu').addClass('blur-in');
});

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
      $('#Header,#TopMenu').removeClass('blur-in');
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
   $('#Header,#TopMenu').removeClass('blur-in');
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any media queries.

Answer (score 0):

As another user has pointed out, you appear to be missing Media Queries. These help with defining styles for specific breakpoints, and thus various screen sizes. A better, more thorough explanation can be [found here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

After getting a general understanding, I would jump down to the section titled "Typical Device Breakpoints" to get where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's a lengthy css,inside the css above,here are the media queries:-

```
/*For phones till ipad pro*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width:  100%;
  height: 80%;


}
.content-img-wrapper .img img{
    /*width:90%;*/
        margin-left: 8px;
    }
}
/* For just phones*/
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.content-img-wrapper{
 flex-direction: column;
}
  .content-img-wrapper .content p {
    /* justify-content: space-around; */
    font-size: 25px;
    transform:unset;

}
.content-img-wrapper .content ul li {
   font-size: 15px;

    transform: translate(-10%,100%);
}
.content {
    transform: translate(15%);
}
.modal-content {
    width:90%;
    min-height: 90%;

transform:unset;
}
i.right{
transform: scale(0.7)translate(0%,-20%) rotate(-45deg);
}

}
@media screen and  (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 360px) {
    .modal{
        padding-top:unset;
        }
.modal-content {

    height: 82%;
}
.content-img-wrapper .content p {

    font-size: 22px;
}

}
@media  screen 
    and (device-width : 375px) 
    and (device-height : 812px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) { 
.modal-content {
    width: 90%;
    height: 64%;

}

}
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 411px) 
  and (device-height: 823px) 

   {
.modal-content {
    width: 90%;
    height: 66%;

}

}

@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 568px) 

   {
.content {
    transform: translate(11%);
}

}
/*Ipad and Ipad pro specific styles*/
@media  screen 
  and (min-width: 768px) 
  and (max-width: 1279px) 
  {
    .content {

    transform: translate(30%);
    }
    .content-img-wrapper .content ul li {

    transform: translate(-2%,132%);
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.content-img-wrapper {
    padding-top: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap:unset;
}
.content-img-wrapper .img img {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
      margin-left: 60px;
}

a.btn-ga {
        transform: translate(0%,80%);
    font-size: 2rem;
        line-height: 3rem;
        width: 29rem;
    height: 3rem;
    }
i.arrow-button {

    transform: scale(1.5)translateY(-25%) rotate(-45deg);
    margin-right: 10px;
}

}
/*For laptops and bigger*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .content-img-wrapper{

    justify-content: space-around;
    transform: translateY(30%);

}
.content-img-wrapper .content {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.modal-content {

  width: 1250px; 

}
.content-img-wrapper .content ul li{

        transform: translate(-4%,200%);
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
a.btn-ga{
    transform: translate(0%,200%);
    width:483px;
    font-size: 2rem;
        line-height: 4rem;
    height:58px;
    }
i.arrow-button {
    border: solid #fff;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-33%) rotate(-45deg);
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#ga-icons {
    font-size: 20px;

}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 800px){
.content-img-wrapper {
    transform: translateY(20%);
}


}
```